# laravel access a eloquent row data by index

Tags: laravel

hello i have the laravel model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

use SoftDeletes;
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
* The database primary key value.
*
* @var string
*/
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
              'name',
              'family',

          ];
}
```

in controller i get a user by id like :

```
$user=User::where('id','=' ,'10')->first () ;
```

in blade i display the family value   :

```
{{$user->family}}
```

i am using :

```
  {{$user[3] }}
```

to get the family value .
can we get the value by index like 2 for name , 
3 for family instead to do it like this $user->name ,or $user->family ?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to access user object by index, not by the properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hope you know what you are doing. As you want to access the User object by index.

Here is the snippet for controller:-

```
$user = User::where('id','=' ,'10')->first();
$user = array_values($user->toArray());
```

Now the $user has an array and you can access in the blade file by index.

**Note that:- This will create an issue when you add more fields or remove some fields.**